# Add elements in vector one at a time and count success rate of obtaining number

Tags: r, vector, simulation, probability

What is the best way to add elements in a vector 1 by 1 until you reach a number or stop the loop if the consecutive elements go negative? From this I need to add a counter/success rate of permutation that does not go below 0. Is this possible?

```
a=c(5,5,-5,-5,5,5,-5)
# Ans: 5 + 5 -5 -5 + 5 +5 -5    

a=c(5,-5,-5,-5,5,5,-5)
# stopped total goes negative after 3rd element
# Ans: 5 - 5 - 5
```

Comment: Where do your elements come from? What are they?

Comment: @Jealie they come from a permutation and are printed into a vector

Comment: I am assuming you are looping around something and you insert one element at a time. In that case you can embed the insert statement within an 'if' statement and insert only if 'sum(a) < 0'.

Comment: See `cumsum`. It won't stop itself, but you can look at where you would have wanted to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage with `cumsum` wich returns the cumulative sum of the elements of your vector.

(The ifelse is if there is no negatives cumulative sum)

```
> a <- c(5,-5,-5,-5,5,5,-5)
> 
> cumsum(a)
[1]   5   0  -5 -10  -5   0  -5
> 
> a[1:ifelse(any(cumsum(a) < 0), which(cumsum(a) < 0)[1], length(a))]
[1]  5 -5 -5
```

Comment: You could simplify the first argument in your `ifelse` to `any(cumsum(a) < 0)`, which I find more readable.